# Weird text when copying from PDF

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, copy-paste

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}
    åäö
\end{document}
```

Making a PDF from this creates a document with the text "åäö". Copying that text (OSX 10.9) results in "aa ̈o ̈"

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default output encoding used by LaTeX is OT1 and fonts in this encoding don't have precomposed accented characters. Therefore `ä` is first transformed into `\"a` which becomes `\accent "7F a`. Thus in the PDF file we get a set of elementary instructions for superimposing the dieresis to the `a`.

Load also

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

so the fonts used will not suffer from this problem, because they cover the glyphs used in several European languages written with the Latin alphabet. Swedish is completely covered.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}

åäö

\end{document}
```